# vs2019 external tool uncrustify hide console

Tags: visual-studio, console, uncrustify

I have been able to successfully add and configure uncrustify as an external tool to vs2019.

The problem I have is that the console window flashes each time uncrustify is executed (via keyboard shortcut).

Is there a way to hide the console window or prevent it from appearing?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the **Use Output window** option for the tool.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. However, I was able to recompile the following extension to work with vs2019. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MariuszBrzeski.CodeBeautifier Btw, your extension Visual Commander also worked. Thank you for developing it and making a version of it for free.